# Postgis - How to work with data type 'geography' via JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgis, mybatis

Working on a web project, which uses `postgresql 9.3` `postgis 2.1`.

There is a column of type `geography` in the table, it just store a `point`.

Now I need to insert / select the type via JDBC with Java object.

After reading `postgis` manual, didn't find much information relevant.

**The questions are:**

1. In java pojo model class, what Java data type should be used for the column?
2. How to write the insert sql?
3. How to write the select sql to retrieve the value and put into Java object?
4. If `mybatis` is used, then does it effect answers to above questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need special types for `POINT` geometries. Just use primitive data types like `double` for the coordinates.

E.g., to insert a new `geography` type via `lon` and `lat` parameters, use [geometry constructor functions](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors):

```
INSERT INTO my_table (geog)
VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:lon, :lat), 4326)::geography);
```

Or get them back as floating point numbers, use [geometry accessor functions](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Accessors):

```
SELECT ST_Y(geog::geometry) AS lat, ST_X(geog::geometry) AS lon FROM my_table;
```

There are other input/output formats, like GeoJSON, WKT, etc.

Comment: Thx, I have refactor my project with the functions that you provided. By the way, before use `ST_X` or `ST_Y`, need cast value to type `geometry`. e.g `ST_X(geog::geometry)`.

Comment: @EricWang correct, some functions need to be cast back/forth to geometry. I've also added links to the geometry constructor / accessor functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you use MyBatis, There is a tiny project for Postgis type in MyBatis. And it has been added to maven central, so you can use it directly from maven.

https://github.com/eyougo/mybatis-typehandlers-postgis

Comment: you help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mybatis, you can have the conversion between latitude and longitude transparently made using a [TypeHandler](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html). Here is how I did it in a scenario like yours, PostGIS, Mybatis, and Gegraphy need. Using TypeHandler makes the handling of different classes you may wrap a geometry type into. In my case Coordinate has two `double` attributes, `latitude` and `longitude`.

Coordinate class

```
public class Coordinate {
    private Double latitude;
    private Double latitude;
    ... getters, setters, etc
}
```

Declare Ibati's TypeHandler

```
@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.JAVA_OBJECT)
@MappedTypes({Coordinate.class})
public class CoordinateTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<Coordinate> {

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Coordinate parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        // Convert Coordinate to Ibatis representation of Postgis point, e.g., "SRID=4326;POINT(2.294801 48.858007)"
        Point point = new Point(parameter.getLongitude(), parameter.getLatitude());
        point.setSrid(4326);
        ps.setString(i, point.toString());
    }

    // Convert data read from Ibatis to actual Coordinate class
    @Override
    public Coordinate getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return from(rs.getString(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public Coordinate getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return from(rs.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public Coordinate getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return from(cs.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    protected Coordinate from(String pointAsText) throws SQLException {
        if (pointAsText != null) {
            Point point = new Point(pointAsText);
            return new Coordinate(point.getY(), point.getX());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then prepare your select on Ibatis' interface. Refer to the usage `'as coordinate'` here, it says to Ibatis to look for the representation of coordinate type, which is the handled by the `CoordinateTypeHandler` you just defined.

It is important to know that `location` bellow is declared as `location geography(POINT, 4326)` on your table definition.

```
@Select("SELECT " +
        "ST_AsText(location) AS coordinate" +
    "FROM " +
        "mytable " +
    "WHERE " +
        "tableattribute = #{myattribute}")
List<Result> myFindMethod(
        @Param("myattribute") Integer myattribute
);
```

This solution will provide a clean abstraction to the Coordinate-kind of class that wraps `latitude` and `longitude` attributes to the `SRID=4326;POINT(2.294801 48.858007)` representation on PostGIS. Considering the solution of Mike T., you would need to rewrite the same `(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:lon, :lat), 4326)::geography)` for every query you are going to create on your API/service.

Using a `TypeHandler` aims to avoid that, once you change/add the representation of you `TypeHandler`, it reflects directly on every query you use `as coordinate`.

Comment: Up voted, great idea, would integrate the code into my utilities :), thanks.